# Optimization problem over a bi-linear function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

Here is my code:

```
f[x1_, x2_] :=Piecewise[{{Min[(2 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x2 + x1*x2 - 
   (1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x1)*(1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x2))/2, 
 (x1 + x2 - x1*x2 + (1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x1)*(1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x2))/2], 
0 <= x1 <= a1 && 0 <= x2 <= a1}, {Min[(1 + b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x2)/a0 + x1*x2 - 
   (1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x1)*(b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x2)/a0))/2, 
 (x1 + x2 - x1*x2 + (1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x1)*(b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x2)/a0))/2], 0 <= x1 <= a1 && a1 <= x2 <= a0}, {Min[(x1 + b0*(1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x1)*(1 - x2) + x2 - x1*x2)/2, 
 (1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x1 + b0*(1 - x2) - b0*(1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x1)*(1 - x2) + x1*x2)/2], 
0 <= x1 <= a1 && a0 <= x2 <= 1}, {Min[(1 + b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x1)/a0 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x2 + x1*x2 - 
   (b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x1)/a0)*(1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x2))/2, 
 (x1 + x2 - x1*x2 + (b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x1)/a0)*(1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x2))/2], a1 <= x1 <= a0 && 0 <= x2 <= a1}, {Min[(2*b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x1)/a0 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x2)/a0 + x1*x2 - (b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x1)/a0)*
    (b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x2)/a0))/2, (x1 + x2 - x1*x2 + (b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x1)/a0)*(b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x2)/a0))/2], 
a1 <= x1 <= a0 && a1 <= x2 <= a0}, {Min[(x1 + b0*(b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x1)/a0)*(1 - x2) + x2 - x1*x2)/2, 
 (b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x1)/a0 + b0*(1 - x2) - b0*(b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x1)/a0)*(1 - x2) + x1*x2)/2], 
a1 <= x1 <= a0 && a0 <= x2 <= 1}, {Min[(1 + b0*(1 - x1) + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x2 + x1*x2 - 
   b0*(1 - x1)*(1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x2))/2, 
 (x1 + x2 - x1*x2 + b0*(1 - x1)*(1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)/a0 + (-1 + b1)/a1)*x2))/2], a0 <= x1 <= 1 && 0 <= x2 <= a1}, {Min[(b1 + b0*(1 - x1) + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x2)/a0 + x1*x2 - b0*(1 - x1)*(b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x2)/a0))/2, 
 (x1 + x2 - x1*x2 + b0*(1 - x1)*(b1 + (((1 - a0)*b0 - b1)*x2)/a0))/2], a0 <= x1 <= 1 && a1 <= x2 <= a0}, {Min[(x1 + b0^2*(1 - x1)*(1 - x2) + x2 - x1*x2)/2, (b0*(1 - x1) + b0*(1 - x2) - b0^2*(1 - x1)*(1 - x2) + x1*x2)/2], 
a0 <= x1 <= 1 && a0 <= x2 <= 1}}, 0]

f1[x_, y_, a0_, b0_, a1_, b1_] := Evaluate@f[x, y]
assumptions = Sequence[0 <= a0 <= 1, 0 <= b0 <= 1, 0 <= a1 <= a0, b0 <= b1 <= 1];
fS = FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> {assumptions}] &;
(m1 = fS@Min[fS@MinValue[#, x] & /@ f1[x, x, a0, b0, a1, b1][[1]]];
m2 = fS@Min[fS@MinValue[#, {x, y}] & /@ f1[x, y, a0, b0, a1, b1][[1]]];
Maximize[{fS[m1 - m2], assumptions}, {a0, b0, a1, b1}] // N) // AbsoluteTiming
```

The solution is based on the answer of @kglr for this question:

[Optimization over a bi-linear function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179425/optimization-over-a-bi-linear-function)

I am out of RAM unfortunately and my computer is trying to use the HDD as an additional memory source. I am wondering whether the RAM usage increases indefinitely or stops somewhere?

I have 4GB, out of which 3.5GB should be usable. The RAM usage is stuck at 2.5GB.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to solve this problem symbolically? When several GB of RAM are needed to process the expressions, why do you expect to get anything interpretable?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I dont actually. I just used the code which I barely understood. So I guess you mean the last Maximize? would it be enough to change it with NMaximize? I dont understand //N or //AbsoluteTiming too.

Comment: Ah, I've just realized that it's about maximin problem. These are notoriously hard. I don't know of a simple way to do it efficiently. Using `NMaximize` (and probably also `NMinValue`) would be one of many ingredients to get this running.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I agree that is is difficult. I mean it is just over some bi-linear function let alone some other complicated functions.. Here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179425/optimization-over-a-bi-linear-function there is one other answer but it doesnt give correct answer for this problem. It gives just zero.

Comment: This code requires 13.5 GB of memory. And I do not understand why it takes so much memory to solve such a simple task.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I don't know either. Were you able to get a result?

Comment: Unfortunately no. After a few hours, it took all the memory and the whole disk, but nothing is out. I stopped it. We need to write another code.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Haha)) when you said 13.5GB I thought it had stopped eating memory. Very hungry program. If we run for a day, he will eat the computer and also the its owner. I think there may be a problem with Mathematica. The user should never be able to run out of memory, in my opinion.

Comment: Apparently, there is a problem with the memory manager in version 11.3. Almost any task requires a lot of memory. And I do not understand why. It is possible that there is a background process, for the maintenance of which memory is needed.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have version 9 and 10. In both versions I had this problem.

Comment: Therefore, we need to write optimized code, and throw all these tricks into the trash.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I can never disagree but I dont know how to write optimized codes in Mathematica. Btw. I was able to get one solution to this problem. I strongly believe that the solution I found is correct but I cannot say that 100$\%$. Here I have a 6 dimensional minimax problem 2 minimization and 6 maximization. This is just the beginning for me. I will have to add at least 2 more dimensions. It took about 1 day to find a solution for this problem and if I increase the dimension to 8, I am afraid that I will not be able to get any solution.. what should one do?

Comment: @kglr do you have any comments?

Comment: Seyhmus, _"I knew I would be present at my funeral; but never expected to deliver the eulogy"_:)

Comment: btw the linked answer is now deleted.

Comment: @kglr please do never delete your answers unless they are wrong. I am thinking about that interesting sentence and hmm...so you were happy to delete it?